# Python Classes to make List of objects

Tags: python, class

I have made a program that lets the user create new vehicles with certain attributes. Now, I need to create an inventory function that will add each vehicle created to a list of all the vehicles and then display them. This is what I have, but it is not working. Should I look more specifically at the inventory function?

```
class Inventory:

    def __init__(self, list1 = []):
        self.list1 = list1[:]
    def addVehicle(self, vehicle):
        self.list1.append(vehicle)
    def Display(self):
        print(self.list1)
```

Comment: Did you happen to learn another object-oriented language before Python, one in which getters and setters were recommended practice?

Comment: How is it not working? Tracebacks? Wrong output?

Comment: when i run the main program the only thing it will output is `[]` and not a list of all the vehicles added.

Answer (score 2):

Someplace you need to call `inventory.addVehicle` (unless I missed it in your code), in order to actually add the recently created object to your inventory.

Another problem is that you call `main` recursively and at the top of `main` you overwrite `inventory`.

Maybe you can refactor it like this:

```
def main():
    inventory = Inventory()

    while True:
        classType = input('Is the vehicle a car, truck, or suv?  ')
        vehicle = None
        if classType == 'car':
            #inputs
            vehicle = Car(make, model, year, mileage, price, doors)
        elif classType == 'truck':
            #inputs
            vehicle = Truck(make, model, year, mileage, price, drive)
        elif classType == 'suv':
            #inputs
            vehicle = SUV(make, model, year, mileage, price, passengers)
        else: print('Unkown vehicle type')
        if vehicle: inventory.addVehicle (vehicle)
        cont = input('Would you like to add another vehicle?  */n  ')
        if cont == 'n': break
    inventory.Display()
```

On a side note: You don't need all those getters and setters: omit the double-underscores and write and read them directly (we are all grown-ups here). If encapsulation is really a concern, then you can use `@property` and `@setter` decorators.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should shorten your code doing like follows (there's absolutely no need, as far as I can see it, to make `inventory` an instance of a class)

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price):
        self.__make    = make
        self.__model   = model
        self.__year    = year
        self.__mileage = mileage
        self.__price   = price

    def iMake(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def iModel(self, model):
        self.__model = model

    def iYear(self, year):
        self.__year = year

    def iMileage(self, mileage):
        self.__mileage = mileage

    def iPrice(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    def getMake(self):
        return self.__make

    def getModel(self):
        return self.__model

    def getYear(self):
        return self.__year

    def getMileage(self):
        return self.__mileage

    def getPrice(self):
        return self.__price

    def Display_Vehicle(self):
        print('Inventory unit: %s' % self.__class__.name)
        print('Make: ' , self.__make)
        print('Model: ', self.__model)
        print('Year: ' , self.__year)
        print('Miles: ', self.__mileage)
        print('Price: ', self.__price)

class Car(Vehicle):
    name = 'Car'
    def __init__(self,make, model, year, mileage, price, x):
        Vehicle.__init__(self,make, model, year, mileage, price)
        self.__doors  = x
    def iDoors(self, doors):  
        self.__doors = doors
    def getDoors(self):
        return self.__doors
    def Display(self):
        self.Display_Vehicle()
        print('Number of doors: ', self.__doors)

class Truck(Vehicle):
    name = 'Truck'
    def __init__(self,make, model, year, mileage, price, x):
        Vehicle.__init__(self,make, model, year, mileage, price)
        self.__drive  = x
    def iDrive(self, drive):  
        self.__drive = drive
    def getDrive(self):
        return self.__drive
    def Display(self):
        self.Display_Vehicle()
        print('Drive type: ', self.__drive)

class SUV(Vehicle):
    name = 'SUV'
    def __init__(self,make, model, year, mileage, price, x):
        Vehicle.__init__(self,make, model, year, mileage, price)
        self.__passengers = x
    def iCapacity(self, passengers):
        self.__passengers = passengers
    def getCapacity(self):
        return self.__passengers
    def Display(self):
        self.Display_Vehicle()
        print('Number of passengers: ', self.__passengers)

def main():
    inventory = []
    while True:
        classType = input('Is the vehicle a car, truck, or suv?  ')
        print (classType)
        make    = input('Please enter the make of the %s: ' % classType)
        model   = input('Please enter the model of the %s: ' % classType)
        year    = input('Please enter the year of the %s: ' % classType)
        mileage = input('Please enter the mileage of the %s: ' % classType)
        price   = input('Please enter the price of the %s: ' % classType)
        if classType == 'car':        
            x = input('Please enter the amount of doors on the car: ')
            inventory.append(Car(make, model, year, mileage, price, x))
        elif classType == 'truck':
            x = input('Please enter 2 wheel or 4 wheel drive for the truck: ')
            inventory.append(Truck(make, model, year, mileage, price, x))
        elif classType == 'suv':
            x = input('Please enter the capacity of the suv: ')
            inventory.append(SUV(make, model, year, mileage, price, x))
        print('\n\n')
        inventory[-1].Display()
        cont = 'go'
        while cont not in ('y','n'):
            cont = input('Would you like to add another vehicle?  y/n  ')
        if cont == 'n':
            print( inventory )
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is a bit of an anti-pattern opposed to OOP. When each object has a type, why give it a property called type? IMHO, really no good practice.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Argument accepted. I changed my code. My idea was to shorten the code of its repetitions but I went too far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use *class variables*. I suggest you add some little code to your `Vehicle`-class:

class Vehicle:

```
all_vehicles = []

def __init__(self, whatever):
    # Your code
    # …
    # and now you just add the vehicle to the list of all vehicles.
    # stored in a class variable
    Vehicle.all_vehicles.append(self)
```

If you want to print all your Vehicles, you just have to

```
print Vehicle.all_vehicles
```

But this only works, if you call the `__init__`-method of Vehicle in every subclass (as it should be in well coded oop).